# How can I update multiple rows in mysql with different criteria in WHERE?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, rows

for eg

```
Set col1 to A WHERE id=X 
set col1 to B WHERE ID=Y
```

ID is unique but not the primary key. I'd like to do this in one update query

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` expression to set the value according to the `ID`:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET col1 = CASE ID WHEN X THEN A
                   WHEN Y THEN B
                   ELSE col1
           END
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecd143/1)

Note the use of an `ELSE` clause so that the value of `col1` doesn't get changed when `ID` is not equal to `X` or `Y`. That can also be achieved with a `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET col1 = CASE ID WHEN X THEN A
                   WHEN Y THEN B
           END
WHERE ID IN (X, Y)
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/938887/1)

Answer (score -1):

You should use multiple statements for that like so:

```
update table1 set col1 = 'A' where id = 1;
update table1 set col1 = 'B' where id = 2;
```